# How to collect all quiz scores for each student in each course

Tags: sql-server

As the title describes, I need to get all quiz scores for each student  in each course. Courses have a varying number of quizzes.

Eventually I am going to write this to a separate DB as a way to archive student data.

The archive table needs to be structured like this:

userID, ULastname, UFirstName, courseID, courseShrtNm, quiz1, quiz2, quiz3....

Here is what I have so far for a select statement:

```
SELECT 
u.id AS userID,
u.lastname AS ULastName,
u.firstname AS UFirstName,
c.id AS courseID,
c.shortname AS courseShrtNm,
cc.id AS courseCat
FROM mp_user u
INNER JOIN mp_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN mp_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid
INNER JOIN mp_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid
INNER JOIN mp_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid
INNER JOIN mp_course_categories cc ON cc.id = c.category

WHERE r.id =5
order by ULastName
```

What I am having problems with is getting the quiz scores since there is a varying number of them per course. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be worth doing your homework on your own.

Comment: I recommend splitting this into more than one table. Have one table for users and another for quizzes. This way you can easily have a variable amount of quizzes per user.

Comment: As @ChrisAlbert says don't do this. What you are trying to do violates 1NF by having repeating groups. This is incredibly problematic. Every time a course has more quizzes you have to change the table and all the queries that access it. Normalization is your friend here.